# Finding cardinality of a two variable polynomial quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

One of my homework questions in my algebra course is to find the cardinality  of the quotient ring 
$$ \frac{Z_5[X,Y]}{(X^2+4Y^4)}
$$
I can't seem to figure out how to approach this sort of problem. My idea was to try to find a surjective homomorphism with kernel (X^2+4Y) that maps to a ring where it is easier to count the elements, since this ring will be isomorphic to the quotient but it just seems to be too clumsy. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $X^2+4Y^4=(X-Y^2)(X+Y^2)$, you could try $P(X,Y)\mapsto P(Y^2,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the cardinality, we can just look at the quotient's structure as an abelian group. Since $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X,Y] \cong (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y][X]$, we can consider elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X,Y]$ as polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y]$. Using the division algorithm, given $f(X,Y) \in (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X,Y]$ we can find unique elements $q(X,Y), r(X,Y) \in (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X,Y]$ such that
$$
f(X,Y) = q(X,Y)(X^2+4Y^4) + r(X,Y)
$$
and $\deg_X(r(X,Y)) < 2$. Thus
$$
f(X,Y) \equiv r(X,Y) = h_0(Y) + X h_1(Y) \pmod{X^2 + 4Y^4}
$$
for some $h_0(Y), h_1(Y) \in (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y]$.
This shows that
$$
\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X,Y]}{(X^2+4Y^4)} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y] \oplus X (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y]
$$
as abelian groups.

Comment: This is very helpful, gives me a new approach for this sort of problem. In the end I found that a ring homomorphism from Z5[X,Y] to Z5[T]xZ5[T] worked as well, mapping f(X,Y) to (f(T^2,T),f(T^2,-T)) , so it is perfectly in sync with your answer as well. Just one question, when I use the division algorithm, can I, at the same time, say that the degree of the remainder in X <2 and in Y<4 , since Y's coefficient is -1 and I could apply the same algorithm to (K[X])[Y]? It would help when I'm trying to prove the remainder is zero in other examples.

Comment: You can have $\deg_X(r) < 2$ of $\deg_Y(r) < 4$, but not both. For instance, you couldn't write $Y^5$ in a form satisfying both conditions. If you found a different solution, please post it! I thought about trying to use the factorization $X^2 - Y^4 = (X - Y^2)(X+Y^2)$, but since the factors aren't comaximal (both are contained in $(X,Y)$), I couldn't see how to use it. It only gave an injection $\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X,Y]}{(X^2+4Y^4)} \hookrightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y] \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[Y]$.

Comment: I think you are right, I probably took the surjectivity aspect a bit too lightly. Thanks for pointing that out.